# consequence of "the best coupling" of two SDEs with different diffusion matrices

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, stochastic-differential-equations

My question comes form a potion of the long [review paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2106.14812.pdf), which is attached below
[image]

In the set-up, $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$ are possibly different, constant diffusion matrices. To my knowledge, if we take the ("cheap") synchronous coupling $B^1_t = B^2_t$, then we can estimate $\mathbb{E}[|X^1_t - X^2_t|^2]$ using for instance Ito isometry or BDG inequality. However, what will be the error estimate $\mathbb{E}[|X^1_t - X^2_t|^2]$ under this new ("the best") coupling? The reference paper [FH16](http://www.lpma-paris.fr/pageperso/fournier/a62.pdf) published on *The Annals of Probability* is overwhelming long and it is also too technical for me. Thanks for any help!

Comment: As the authors state, $W_2(\mathcal{L}(X_t^1),\mathcal{L}(X_t^2))^2$  is precisely a "dynamical version" (meaning that it involves time) of the standard 2-Wasserstein distance between two multivariate normal distributions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric#Normal_distributions with $\mu_1 = X^1_0$, $\mu_2=X^2_0$, $C_1 = t a_1$ and $C_2 = t a_2$.  This result is straightforward to prove.

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee thanks! But what are $C_1$ and $C_2$? It seems that it appears out of the blue. I also have no clue as to why you mentioned that "This result is straightforward to prove"

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee thank you very much. But in my original post above, there are no constants such as $C_1$ and $C_2$, I am wondering where do these constants come from...

Comment: @NawafBou-Rabee Thank you! But there is a mistake: $X_t^2 = X_0^2 + \sigma_2 U(a_1,a_2) B_t^1$ instead of $X_t^2 = X_0^2 + U(a_1,a_2) B_t^1$. Also, it is hard to "simplify" $\mathbb{E}[ | X_t^1 - X_t^2|^2 ]$ and compare with the corresponding bound obtained via the synchronous coupling...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $\sigma_1 = a_1^{1/2}$ and $\sigma_2 = a_2^{1/2}$.  Consider the coupling
$$ X^1_t = X_0^1 + a_1^{1/2} B^1_t \quad \text{and} \quad X^2_t = X_0^2 + a_2^{1/2} U(a_1, a_2) B_t^1 \;.
$$ Here $U(a_1,a_2) =  a_2^{-1/2} a_1^{-1/2} (a_1^{1/2} a_2 a_1^{1/2} )^{1/2}$ is an orthogonal matrix since $$
U(a_1,a_2) U(a_1, a_2)^T = a_2^{-1/2} a_1^{-1/2} (a_1^{1/2} a_2 a_1^{1/2} ) a_1^{-1/2} a_2^{-1/2} = I  
$$ where $I$ is the identity matrix.  As a shorthand, let $A =a_1^{1/2} -  a_2^{1/2} U(a_1, a_2) $, so that
$$
X_t^1 - X_t^2 = X_0^1 - X_0^2 + A B_t^1 \;.
$$

Then
\begin{align}
E[|X^1_t - X^2_t|^2] &= |X_0^1 - X_0^2|^2 + E[| A B^1_t|^2] = |X_0^1 - X_0^2|^2 + E[(A B^1_t)^T (A B^1_t)]  \\
&= |X_0^1 - X_0^2|^2 + E[\operatorname{Trace}( ( A B^1_t)^T (A B^1_t)) ] \\
&= |X_0^1 - X_0^2|^2 + E[\operatorname{Trace}( A (B^1_t) (B^1_t)^T A^T ) ] \\
&= |X_0^1 - X_0^2|^2 + t \operatorname{Trace}( A A^T )  
\end{align}
where we used the cyclic property of the trace and the fact that $E[ (B^1_t) (B^1_t)^T]= t I$.

To finish, \begin{align}
&\operatorname{Trace}( A A^T ) = \operatorname{Trace}( (a_1^{1/2} -  a_2^{1/2} U(a_1, a_2)) (a_1^{1/2} -  a_2^{1/2} U(a_1, a_2))^T ) \\
&= \operatorname{Trace}( a_1 - a_2^{1/2} U(a_1, a_2) a_1^{1/2} - a_1^{1/2}  U(a_1, a_2)^T a_2^{1/2} + a_2^{1/2} U(a_1, a_2) U(a_1, a_2)^T a_2^{1/2}   ) \\
&=  \operatorname{Trace}( a_1 - 2 a_1^{1/2}  a_2^{1/2} U(a_1, a_2) + a_2    ) \\
&= \operatorname{Trace}( a_1 - 2 (a_1^{1/2} a_2 a_1^{1/2} )^{1/2} + a_2  ) 
\end{align}
where again we used the cyclic property of the trace and that $U(a_1,a_2)$ is an orthogonal matrix. Combining the above we obtain
$$
E[|X^1_t - X^2_t|^2] = |X_0^1 - X_0^2|^2 + t  \operatorname{Trace}( a_1 + a_2 - 2 (a_1^{1/2} a_2 a_1^{1/2} )^{1/2}  ) \;,
$$ as required.  This is indeed a dynamical (i.e., time-dependent) version of the [2-Wasserstein distance between two multivariate normal distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasserstein_metric#Normal_distributions).

In contrast, for the synchronous coupling,
$$
X^1_t = X_0^1 + a_1^{1/2} B^1_t \quad \text{and} \quad X^2_t = X_0^2 + a_2^{1/2} B_t^1 \;,
$$ we obtain:
$$
E[|X^1_t - X^2_t|^2] = |X_0^1 - X_0^2|^2 + t  \operatorname{Trace}( a_1 + a_2 - 2 a_1^{1/4} a_2^{1/2} a_1^{1/4}   ) \;.
$$
As discussed further in Section 2 of the reference below, we note that the synchronous coupling is optimal with respect to the 2-Wasserstein distance when $a_1$ and $a_2$ commute, since in that case $U(a_1,a_2)=I$.

*Givens, Clark R.; Shortt, Rae Michael*, [**A class of Wasserstein metrics for probability distributions**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1307/mmj/1029003026), Mich. Math. J. 31, 231-240 (1984). [ZBL0582.60002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0582.60002).

Comment: Thank you very much! Professor